# select outliers based on sigma and standard deviation in sql

Tags: sql, outliers

The sample data is like this.

[image]

I want select outliers out of 4 sigma for each class.
I tried

```
  select  value,class,AVG(value) as mean, STDEV(value)as st, size  from Data
 having value<mean-2*st OR value>mean+2*st group by calss
```

it seems does not work. Should I use having or where clause here?

The results I want is the whole 3rd row and 8th row.

Comment: In the sample data provided, which is `boh`? which is `ndc`?

Comment: lso have a look [here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/121071/can-we-use-leave-one-out-mean-and-standard-deviation-to-reveal-the-outliers/121075?noredirect=1#comment230920_121075)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the condition you are looking at is a property of the row, use `where` i.e. `where class = 1` (all rows with class 1) or `where size > 2` (all rows with size > 2).  When the condition is a property of a set of rows you use `group by ... having`  e.g. `group by class having avg(value) > 2` (all *classes* with average value > 2).

In this case you want `where` but there is a complication.  You don't have enough information in each row alone to write the necessary `where` clause, so you will have to get it through a subquery.

Ultimately you want something like `SELECT value, class, size FROM Data WHERE value < mean - 2 *st OR value > mean + 2*st;`  however you need a subquery to get `mean` and `st`.

One way to do this is:

```
SELECT value, Data.class, size, mean, st FROM Data, 
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT class, AVG(value) AS mean, STDEV(value) AS st 
  FROM Data GROUP BY class
) AS stats ON stats.class = Data.class
WHERE value < mean - 2 * st OR value > mean + 2 * st;
```

This creates a subquery which gets your means and standard deviations for each class, joins those numbers to the rows with matching classes, and then applies your outlier check.